# Proper way to create "persistent" RAM fs

Tags: synchronization, overlayfs

I'm going to reduce SSD writes, so I'd like to keep changes to some directories (like /var/log or browser cache) in memory and syncing to permanent storage periodically. I should reduce memory size as much as possible, so

- only changes should be saved to memory;
- changes in memory should be stored compressed (zram)
- after periodical (10-30 min or so on poweroff time) syncing to persistent storage changes should be removed from memory.

What is a better way to do this? I can get first 2 items using `overlayfs`, but I'm not sure how to sync merged dir to lower online and clean upper dir in proper way.

Comment: Before trying to set this up, have you actually measured that those things are a problem? Because I'd guess they won't be, on any half-recent SSD. You can usually get write counters and percent of lifetime used from an SSD via smartctl.

Comment: @derobert, smartctl would not calculate TBW for each directory separately, I've not measured writes yet, but browser usually causes a lot of I/O operations. Well, of course swap would produces much more.